# Wordpress Multisite requires to add code to Web.config

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, multisite

I have a Wordpress website that I want to deploy to a hosting service
My website has multisite activated and added the wp.config and .htacsess code on my local and works perfectly

When I uploaded my Wordpress folder to the server and wanted to activate multisite it says I have to add code to wp.config file and web.config file not .htaccess

When I do this the sites show up in my dashboard but Whenever I click on them it redirects me the main site also whenever I click on the dashboard of one of the sites it redirects me to the dashboard of main site

I use the latest version of wordpress
MySQL databse
And sharkasp hosting services

I tried to edit the urls of the sites on my database

Tried to delete web.config file and just use the .htacsess file then it says file not found when I click on any of the sites

Tried deleting .htaccess
file and just keep the web.config file

Comment: Just for the record: The name  of the access file is `.htaccess`, not `.htacsess` as you wrote several times in your question. If you really named it like that, that's the first thing you have to change...

Comment: Thank you for your comment , No I just misspelled it here